# Discrepancy between implementation logic and debug print in binary tree

Tags: c++, debugging, c++14, binary-tree

I am attempting a binary tree implementation. I am using a `std::list` to represent the actual binary tree.

I have written a lambda function `lnkNodes` as part of the implementation, to link together the various nodes of the binary tree. The logic adopted for linking the nodes has been provided as a comment in the source code, which can be downloaded from the link given below.

Link for downloading the source code:

[Source Code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c_MbaOfN_zFt-FOR0IUhmRu-Bx5EdF1G)

The two relevant files are `stack_overflow.hpp` and `stack_overflow.cpp`.

I use the following command for compiling the code, using the relevant debug flags:

```
g++ -D<debug flag> -ggdb -std=c++14 -Wall stack_overflow.cpp
```

I use the debug flags `DBG1` and `DBG2` to enable different debug prints from within the code, and the discrepancy I am seeing from the intended logic of the implementation based on the debug print in each case, has been discussed below.

The output due to enabling each of the debug flags (captured using the script utility) has also been uploaded to the above link. The corresponding file names are `DBG1_log.txt` and `DBG2_log.txt` respectively.

**Debug flag DBG1**

*Vide DBG1_log.txt*

The issue here is that for each node, except node 1, the parent node printed is not in accordance with the implementation logic (vide comment line no.s 131-145 in `stack_overflow.hpp`). For instance, for node 3, the parent should be node 1. There is a similar discrepancy in the case of all the nodes.

However, the child nodes for each node are output in accordance with the implementation logic.

The above situation is puzzling for me, since as per the code segment in lines 168-171 and 184-185 in the `stack_overflow.hpp` file, the linkage is established in both directions, i.e., from the parent to the children and vice versa.

**Debug flag DBG2**

*Vide DBG2_log.txt*

In this case, the same data repeats for the parent and children data. I am printing the node data immediately after exiting the previous do-while loop (vide line no. 203 in `stack_overflow.hpp`), wherein the nodes are linked together and the debug print corresponding to the debug flag DBG1 is generated.

I am puzzled by the fact that even though I am printing the contents of the same container during and after the linkage (vide line no.s 149 and 204 in the `stack_overflow.hpp` file), the outputs are as different as chalk and cheese.

I would welcome your insights to overcome these issues.

Comment: Why not just step through the code in your debugger to see where things are going awry ?

Comment: @PaulR I am relatively inexperienced with GDB and so could not figure out how to print the veariable names within the context of template function definition. I have resorted to debug prints instead and in spite of extensive debugging, am not sure where is the logical flaw with the code.

Comment: Using an IDE can take away a lot of the pain of debugging, particularly learning how to use gdb. But if you're stuck with command line builds then you may just need to invest more time in getting to grips with gdb and/or logging debug output. Another useful technique is to reduce your program to the smallest example that shows the problem ("divide and conquer").

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (emphasis on "minimal", and also that the code must be in the question itself)

Comment: Can any of the members educate me about how I could revise this question with a MWE, with the code in the text of the question itself, as pointed out by AndyG? Is it advisable to ask a follow-up question? If so, how can I do so? I could not find a satisfactory answer about this, based on my search within Stack Overflow. Or should I go ahead and edit my original post? Please advise.